# How do i reset my game?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

At the end of my game/ death creen i want the user to be able to restart but its not as simple as jumping back to frame 1 as everything ends up all over the place.

is their code to reset your game when u hit a button ?

Thanks Lochy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no code to reset the game when you hit a button, you have to re-set all the variables, movie clips, etc.

You can use built in for-each loops to loop through the variables but I assume since your variables are probablynot all the same value this is not a good option.

The best practice in your case (well, if you want to keep it really basic) is make a method that initializes the game and then call it whenever you need to.

Here is a tutorial on functions in AS3:
http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3functions/

Comment: Great answer. I will add a HUGE gotcha here in regards to going back to an earlier movieclip, if this is relevent: DO NOT USE SCENES! If you try to back-navigate screens, the animation and code both malfunction in many, many ways.